# How to extract path from Windows shortcut in R?

Tags: r

I have a shortcut to a file (or a folder) under Windows, and I would like to resolve the path name under R and use that info to open a file.

The shortcut is called `shortcut.lnk` and it is placed in my working directory, and the shortcut is directed to another place, say `C:\Users\XX\Desktop\something.txt`

I would like to extract the path name of the shortcut to use that info to open the file, something like: `read.table(resolved.link)`. I tried `Sys.readlink`, but it does not work on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could help you :

```
library(R.utils)

lnk <- readWindowsShortcut("C:/Users/indi/Desktop/a.lnk")
lnk$pathname
```

More about it [here](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/R.utils/html/readWindowsShortcut.html)